# crack the key or not: generated key

Tags: cryptography

---

Let $T \in F^{n \times n}$ , $F$ be a field

Let $U_1, U_2 \in F^{n \times n}$ be randomly chosen by user 1 resp. user 2.

user1 sends $U_1\cdot T$ to user2 , user2 sends $T\cdot U_2$ to user1 .

Both are now able to compute the secret key $K=U_1\cdot T\cdot U_2$ .

---

Exercise: Compute $K$ in polynomial time (in the size of the matrix ring) or prove that the protocol is secure!

---

My tries:

Computing the inverse is a polynomial thing, at least in $n$. Gauss elimination does it in $O(n^3)$ But what's the difference to polynomial time "in size of the matrix ring" ?

Well I can not compute $K$ by inverting $U_1\cdot T$ which has $T^{-1}\cdot U_1^{-1}$ as inverse. Then if I combine this one with any $T\cdot U_2$ or $U_2^{-1}\cdot T^{-1}$ I do not get a reasonable result. Well okay I can get

$U_2^{-1}\cdot T^{-1}\cdot U_1\cdot T$ but what does it help?

Does anyone of you see an ansatz? Would you prove the communication here to be secure and how would one do that?

Regards

Comment: Presumably we are to compute $R$, not $K$.  Is $T$ public?  If not, how do the users get it?

Comment: If the user knows $T$, why not compute $T^{-1}$ and then $U_1*T*T^{-1}*T*U_2$?

Comment: What is $T$? A (randomly chosen) shared secret between user1 and user2 or a public constant?

Comment: This reminds me of HDCP. Crosby at al. have done a [cryptanalysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.5690).

Comment: @Ross: I have suggested edits to resolve the name collisions (in favor of $K$ for the key, renaming the field to $F$)

Comment: HDCP uses only vectors per users. Thus, this resembles HDCP sessions with $n$ producers, $n$ consumers in all possible combinations, so $K$ is a matrix of the HDCP session keys for every transmitter-receiver combination, each key being a $56$-bit value.

Comment: In HDCP, $F$ is finite (and it's actually just a ring, not a field). In such finite settings, it can well happen that the exchanged matrices do not have full rank. Thus $\operatorname{coker}(U_1\cdot T)\subseteq\operatorname{coker} K$ and $\ker(T\cdot U_2)\subseteq\ker K$. Thus, the protocol leaks information about $K$. In that sense, the protocol cannot be secure. But the question implicitly assumes invertability. Are rank deficiencies allowed or not?

Comment: Well I also think that T is a public matrix that has been sent and could be catched up in advance?  Could it be cracked if T was unknown?

Comment: If $T$ were public, $K$ could be computed as noted in @DKal's comment. Therefore I suppose that $T$ is not known to the eavesdropper. In the context of this question however $T$ is a secret shared between user$_1$ and user$_2$.

Comment: okay but how to compute it WITHOUT knowing T?